# mapView setRegion:region shows nothing in the simulator

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using ADClusterMapView as a mapview, and I can't see anything but a blue screen in the simulator when I add a [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; I can see the map without this line of code. I am pretty sure I can get the coordinate with locationController.locationManager.location.coordinate. When it runs in the simulator, All I can see is a green screen and Legal link on the left bottom and a Autonavi on the right bottom.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.mapView.delegate = self;

        locationController = [[LocationController alloc] init];
        [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationController.locationManager.location.coordinate, 10000, 10000);
        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the property `showUserLocation` enabled?

Comment: Also make sure that your simulator is emulating any location in Debug > Location

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times.  You cannot expect to retrieve the location _immediately_ after calling startUpdatingLocation.  You have to use the didUpdateToLocation/didUpdateLocations delegate method.

Comment: I have add the setRegion method in the didUpdateToLocation delegate, and it worked. Thanks, @AnnaKarenina

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are selection your current location when you are running application on simulation .

[image]